# Series RL Circuit Transient Analysis

Tags: resistors, inductor, differential, series

I have worked through a question and I am unsure if my answer is correct. It is a series RL circuit with a switch that closes at t=0, supplied by a dc source, which I am trying to derive an expression for the current i, when the switch is closed.

Something like the circuit below:

[image]

***My answer is: i(t) = V/R e^(t/T)***

But does this not represent the discharging current as an exponentional decay rather than a growth? I can show all my workings out if it is not correct.

***I thought the current when the switch is pressed should be represented by:***

***i(t) = V/R ( 1 - e^(t/T) )***

***EDIT***

The image below shows the only way I know how to derive an equation for the instantaneous current in this circuit:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Neither of your proposed answers is correct. One predicts the current going to infinity as *t* increases, the other predicts current going to negative infinity. You're looking for a solution where the current goes to V/R as *t* goes to infinity.

Comment: This is the simplest RL circuit possible with the solution readily available at request.

Comment: @The Photon But surely you can derive an equation to give a current value at any time after t = 0+ ?

Comment: The sign of the signal it's a sin!

Comment: @David, yes you can. I'm trying to give you a hint how to work out that equation without just giving it to you. The point of my comment is if you think about the limit as t goes to infinity, you can see that neither of the two equations you showed can be the correct equation.

Comment: @The Photon Oh should the exponential function power be (-Rt/L) then ?

Comment: Can you state (and solve) a simple differential equation for the current?

Comment: @Phil Freedenberg See edited question